# C++ application as Gemfire client?

Tags: gemfire

I am aware that a Java client can register as a client in a client-server model and register the Regions it is interested in. Also, when the data changes on the server, the data will automatically be sent to the client.

Is it possible to have this with a C++ client and a Java server?

Regards,
Yash

Answer (score 0):

Definitely. Gemfire has a C++ client that supports pretty much everything the java client supports, including getting updates pushed to the client. Check out the documentation here:

http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/docs-gemfire/gemfire_nativeclient/about_native_client_users_guide.html